# Why doesn't this code result in recursion?

Tags: javascript

Given this code:

```
function foo()
{
  if (!foo)
  {
    //blah blah blah some code here
    foo = true;
  }
}
```

What exactly does this do?  Why is it not creating a recursive call?

Comment: A function-object must be *called/invoked/applied* - e.g. with `()` - for recursion to occur. Remember that functions in JavaScript are just objects. The expression `foo` merely evaluates to a value (which is a function object here) while `foo()` evaluates foo and then applies the function operator (which would "call foo").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might create a recursion :

```
function foo()
{
  if (!foo()) // <=== notice the ()
  {
    //blah blah blah some code here
    foo = true;
  }
}
```

But there, without the parenthesis, `foo` isn't executed. The tests only checks the variable `foo` doesn't evaluate as true, and then replaces it with the boolean `true`. It's a weird code but not a recursion.

Note that we're not sure, inside the function, that `foo` is the function, as the code could be like this :

```
function foo() {
  if (!foo)
  {
    //blah blah blah some code here
    foo = true;
  }
}    
var f = foo;
foo = 0;
f(); // this would result in foo being true
```

Comment: It's not so easy to come immediately with such an example as any sane coder doesn't write this kind of code to begin with...

Comment: I've been doing Test Automation coding in JavaScript for 8 years, and today is the first time I've EVER seen this construct, and it boggled my mind.

Comment: And WHY would anyone do this?

Comment: Well, I found out he was trying to make sure his function didn't run more than once during the run, but didn't realize he wasn't assigning the foo to a global variable declared in some other JS file...

Answer (score 0):

Its not calling itself, just checking to see that a variable by that name exists/ is truthy.  The function could be renamed and foo could refer to something else completely by the time it is called.

So to be clear, recursion occurs when a function calls itself

```
function foo(){

  foo();

}
```

whereas what you're doing is just looking up the current value of foo without attempting to call it.

```
!foo  //if foo is defined as a function or other truthy object, is true
```